# nodejs mobwrite on windows

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm trying to setup nodejs mobwrite. I have node working & python installed, and I followed the simple setup steps, but I keep getting this console error in the browser.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
http://localhost:8000/mobwrite/sync
```

https://github.com/mjpizz/node-mobwrite

I'm a bit of a newb when it comes to nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.
Copy mobwrite_daemon.py from `node_modules/mobwrite/ext/google-mobwrite/daemon`, and put it in the directory above it. Dbl click on that to start it in python.

Then start up mobwrite in nodejs. woila!